# How to diagram calls within an application at a high level?

Tags: uml, diagram

I am not a big fan of UML. I believe UML is great in some rare instances, however I do not want to use a UML diagram to show a high level flow of calls through my application. Problem is - most of the tools (visio, lucidchart, websequencediagrams) force the user to either draw a very detailed UML diagram, or a sequence diagram. There is nothing that would be like a high-level version of a UML diagram. Or is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "higher level" UML diagram. UML has 12 (or was it 12? I can't remember)  and you must choose from one of them,  the best that fits your needs.

For a high level flow of calls I like activity diagrams, even though the objects that own the functions are harder to see. Sequence diagrams are a waste of time and space IMHO .